# meta box value does not show in wordpress loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, meta

I faced very weird error, there is a post type "author", and I show the author list in post type "articles", the list shows all authors successfully and also save successfully, but when I want to show them in front end the author does not shown in loop but when I `print_r("author")` the array show me selected authors but in loop there is no author. Here is my code:

I also used foreach loop.

Functions.php

```
<?php
    function ct_downlaod_meta($post){
        $opt_meta_author = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'opt_meta_author', true);

        echo '<select name="opt_meta_author[]" id="opt_meta_author" multiple="multiple">';
        $val = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'opt_meta_author', true);
        $q = get_posts('post_type=author&post_parent=0&numberposts=-1&orderby=menu_order&order=ASC');
        $val_array = explode('<br />', $val); echo $val_array;

        foreach ($q as $obj)
        {
            echo '<option value="'.$obj->post_title.'"'.selected($obj->post_title, $val);
            if(in_array($obj->post_title, $val_array)) { echo ' selected="selected"'; };
            echo '>'.$obj->post_title.'</option>';
        }
        echo '</select>';
    }

    add_action('save_post','save_download_meta_data');
    function save_download_meta_data(){
        global $post;

        $opt_meta_author = implode('<br />',$_POST['opt_meta_author']);

        update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'opt_meta_author', $opt_meta_author);
    }
?>
```

author-bio.php

```
<?php
    $opt_meta_author_array = explode('<br />', get_post_meta($post->ID, 'opt_meta_author', true));

    $args = array(
        'post__in' => $opt_meta_author_array,
        'post_type' => 'author',
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => 'ASC',
    );

    print_r($args);

    $author = new WP_Query($args);

    if($author->have_posts()) :
?>
        <h3 id="entry-author-title"><?php _e('About The Author(s)', 'framework') ?></h3>
<?php
    while($author->have_posts()) :
        $author->the_post();
?>
    <section id="entry-author" class="clearfix">
    <div style=" margin-bottom:12px; float:left; width:100%; padding-bottom:5px;">
        <div class="gravatar">
        <?php
            if(has_post_thumbnail()){
                the_post_thumbnail( array( 70, 70 ) );
            }
            else{
                echo '<img src="http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/6179f2642031d79f16bf2f03f0f66df9?s=70&d=http%3A%2F%2F0.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D70&r=G" />';
            }
        ?>
        </div>
       <?php /*?> <h4><?php echo the_title() ?></h4><?php */?>
        <div style="width:100%; margin:0 0px;">
            <?php //echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'txt_meta_country', true); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="entry-author-desc">
          <?php echo the_content() ?>
        </div>
    </div></section>
    <?php
            endwhile;
        endif;
    ?>
```

When i print_r($args); the array give me true result

```
Array ( [post__in] => Array ( [0] => Andrew Turnell [1] => Adrian Gimpel ) [post_type] => author [orderby] => title [order] => ASC )
```

but in loop is empty result.

Answer (score 0):

So one day delay i found a solution on my own in functions.php

```
<?php
    function ct_downlaod_meta($post){
        $opt_meta_author = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'opt_meta_author', true);

        echo '<select name="opt_meta_author[]" id="opt_meta_author" multiple="multiple">';
        $val = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'opt_meta_author', true);
        $q = get_posts('post_type=author&post_parent=0&numberposts=-1&orderby=menu_order&order=ASC');
        $val_array = explode('<br />', $val); echo $val_array;

        foreach ($q as $obj)
        {
            echo '<option value="'.$obj->ID.'"'.selected($obj->ID, $val);
            if(in_array($obj->ID, $val_array)) { echo ' selected="selected"'; };
            echo '>'.$obj->post_title.'</option>';
        }
        echo '</select>';
    }

    add_action('save_post','save_download_meta_data');
    function save_download_meta_data(){
        global $post;

        $opt_meta_author = implode('<br />',$_POST['opt_meta_author']);

        update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'opt_meta_author', $opt_meta_author);
    }
?>
```

in author-bio.php i not change any thing and my code is running well